# How to fix my batch file to open the appropriate program?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exe

I'm attempting to write a batch file that will move to the specified directory and then run the command to open my desired program. Specifically I want it to run the command **`HardwareSimulator`** so it will open the software nand2tetris provides.

I've gotten it to move to the directory I want, but the opening is my issue. Code is displayed below. I'm guessing **`start`** isn't the correct command since when I run, it just runs an infinite loop of opening cmd prompts.

My second question would be: can I only go into sub-directories of where my batch file is already stored? It would be easier to store it in my desktop, so I can just click it whenever, but I can't seem to make it back out of a directory and then go down into another.

```bat
start cmd
pushd \nand2tetris\projects\P1Codes
start HardwareSimulator
pause
```

Comment: You don't need `start cmd`. Running the batch file has already started a cmd instance - it's what's executing the batch file. Remove that line entirely. You can probably remove `start` from `start HardwareSimulator` also. Try doing both of those things and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: and DONT name your batch file `HardwareSimulator.bat` !!

Comment: It didn't change anything. What's wrong with that title?

Comment: you are calling your batch file from your batch file (a.k.a  "infinite loop") Either rename your batchfile or call the executable with it's extension (I guess, it's `HardwareSimulater.exe`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ..\ to go back a directory.
For instance, if you had nand2tetris in your downloads folder you could get to it from the desktop with this script. Also make sure to to include the file extension.

```
pushd ..\Downloads\nand2tetris\projects\P1Codes
start HardwareSimulator.exe
pause
```